# Manipulation of sesame server repositories (owl ontology) in java servlet

Tags: eclipse, rdf, owl, sesame

I'm trying to connect a web application (eclipse) with my Sesame repository server (sesame 2.6.3) both of them are running in my local machine under the same Apache Tomcat 6.0.29. I found the sesame user guide here : http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/users/ch08.html#d0e835, the part "8.2.2. Querying a repository" is exactly what i'm hoping to do but the problem that i cant find where do i put the given code.. to more explain my problem: i want to manipulate the ontology from a jsp page (querying the ontology) so when i found the connection code, the querying code, the code for evaluating a tuple query... i didn't know where to put them Please help! 
Thank you

Comment: Duplicate of question on answers.semanticweb.com: http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/16475/manipulation-of-sesame-server-repositories-in-java-servlet . An answer is provided there but it's not quite clear what exactly the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

Put your code in a JSP. Then, based on the logic in the JSP, the repository will be able to be queried. If you have trouble, post more details about what you are doing and what is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is the code i put but it doens't work, can you help me to find what is wrong with it?

Comment: <%@ page import org.openrdf.repository.Repository;%> <%@ page import org.openrdf.repository.http.HTTPRepository;%> <%@ page import java.util.List;%> <%@ page import org.openrdf.OpenRDFException;%> <%@ page import org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryConnection;%> <%@ page import org.openrdf.query.TupleQuery;%> <%@ page import org.openrdf.query.TupleQueryResult;%> <%@ page import org.openrdf.query.BindingSet;%> <%@ page import org.openrdf.query.QueryLanguage;%> <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> <title>Sesame XX</title> </head>

Comment: <body> <% public static void main (String args[]) { //accessing to the repository String sesameServer = "http://localhost:8080/openrdf-sesame"; String repositoryID = "ontoProthese"; Repository myRepository = new HTTPRepository(sesameServer, repositoryID); myRepository.initialize(); //querying the repository try { RepositoryConnection con = myRepository.getConnection(); try {

Comment: String queryString = "SELECT x, y FROM {x} p {y}"; //replaced by the needed query TupleQuery tupleQuery = con.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SERQL, queryString); TupleQueryResult result = tupleQuery.evaluate(); try { System.out.println("resultat ="+result); // do something with the result } finally { result.close(); } } finally { con.close(); } } catch (OpenRDFException e) { // handle exception } } %> </body> </html>

Comment: I'm so sorry the code is not clear! but i can't put it in one comment :/

Comment: @Meriem, see answer on  http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/16475/manipulation-of-sesame-server-repositories-in-java-servlet